# Find intersecting polygon within a layer

Tags: qgis, geometry

I would like to find all polygons, which intersect another polygon within the same layer. I thought the geometry checker could do the job, but it doesn't.

[image]

All polygons are intersecting except one, but I get no geometry errors. What I am doing wrong? (QGIS 3.8)

Comment: do you mean intersects?  Or just overlaps?  Because adjecent polygons with common borders will be selected too if you use the intersects-predicate.

Comment: A geometry error occurs when rings overlap each other *within a single geometry*. You appear to want to validate topology with respect to all other shapes, so your selection of the answer is at odds with your stated goal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think self-intersections here only refers to intersections **within** features (*with "edge overlappings" if i may say so ...*) not **between** features ... There's a nice tool in SAGA toolbox called **Polygon self intersections** (*... that should be its right name ...*) which is doing exactly what u seem to be expecting ....

Answer (score 6):

It is better to use `Topology Checker` tool not `Check Geometries`. Topology Checker is located under `Vector -> Topology Checker`, then click on configure button and define a new rule `Must not overlap`.

Here is an example:

This is a polygon shapefile which has overlap polygons as well as separate polygons.

[image]

Go to Configure in the Topology Checker tool.

[image]

1. Current Rule: select the polygon layer
2. Must not Overlap
3. Add Rule
4. Click OK

[image]

Click on Validate Extent or Validate All as you like

[image]

Then the overlap area will be highlighted.

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is working fine to highlight the errors, but unfortunately you can not select them to solve the problems (like geometry checker does)

Comment: @MAP Yes I agree. Anyway, I am glad you find a solution for your problem.

Answer (score 5):

you can do it with virtual layer and sql.

Assuming that your layer has an id called "id".  you can do following query

```
select a.* 
from your_layer as a, your_layer as b
where st_intersects(a.geometry, b.geometry) and a.id <> b.id
```

or you can just use 'topology checker'.  If you do not see it, just activate it in the plugins